# Convert sf POLYGON to character

Tags: r, r-sf

I ma really new to E `sf` package. I want to convert POLYGON sf object:

```
g <- st_as_sfc('POLYGON ((463476 5055839, 464025.2 5055839, 464025.2 5057109, 463476 5057109, 463476 5055839))')
```

as character object. Function `as.character` returns different outout:

```
as.character(g[[1]])
```

This returns

```
 "c(463476, 464025.2, 464025.2, 463476, 463476, 5055839, 5055839, 5057109, 5057109, 5055839)"
```

which is not what I want.

Comment: what do you want?

Comment: I want to convert sfg object to character object but keep same form.

Comment: So do you just want a string?

Comment: yes, just string

Comment: You want the original WKT string back? `POLYGON (...` etc etc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the original WKT text back, use `st_as_text`:

```
> st_as_text(g)
[1] "POLYGON ((463476 5055839, 464025.2 5055839, 464025.2 5057109, 463476 5057109, 463476 5055839))"
```